# rgbdslam and octomap

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone I'm new to ROS and I have the following questions:

how do I get rgbdslam to work with octomap?

I have successfully installed the package and its dependencies to the point that I can launch

roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

but I don't know how to capture a 3D representation of room.
if I press "space" or "enter" I only get one image of the kinect, but what should I do to get the full representation of the room?

also what should I do to get this map saved on octomap?

Also this is the error that I'm receiving:

```
[FATAL] [1366306714.012014901]: Can't run SiftGPU
[FATAL] [1366306717.289295636]: SiftGPU cannot be used. Detection of keypoints failed
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61063/rgbdslam-and-octomap/) by [fontbona](https://answers.ros.org/users/4709/fontbona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems you lack GPU support on your system (small laptop? virtual machine?).
Maybe you just need to install proprietary drivers?

Otherwise, in the launchfile, try changing both occurrences of "SIFTGPU" to "SIFT" (painfully slow), "ORB" (fast but high errors) or "SURF" (medium speed/quality).

P.S: After recording the map, just use "OctoMap->Save Octomap" to create the octomap.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1